# How to integrate an external web ASP.NET control into a SharePoint application's page?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-controls

How to integrate an external web ASP.NET control into a SharePoint application's page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you mean by External Website's **control**? You can use the [page view webpart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA100240451033.aspx) to load an external page/ Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: We use some ASP.NET Web Controls which we need to use for a SharePoint application's page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this article about creating an Application page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732.aspx)?

Essentially, inside your application page you can reference the DLL:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
```

Then register a tag prefix:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Then you can use your controls:

```
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,approve_pagetitle%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
```

Instead of SharePoint, you'll be using the DLL that contains your ASP.NET web controls.

Comment: A variation of this is the Son Of Smart Part type tools. They essentially wrap a server based User Control within a web part. This of course assumes the user control exists within the SharePoint root folder, etc